# TSQL full join with special formatting

Tags: t-sql

I have a nice lady who wants specific formatting on output, and I see that it's very special though against common rules, can you advice if I can achive this somehow with `TSQL`.  I pasted sample input and wanted output. This is I think kind of FULL JOIN but need do more cleaning , bit lost here. My first project. Tried to convince her use 2 separate tables for output to maintain some integrity but failed, so taking this a a challenge)!  There is NO relationship between `LineOrd` and `LinePr`. I composed something with multiple steps but feel should be someting more elegant then doing 4-5 steps..
Best

```
DROP TABLE If exists #o
CREATE TABLE #o (OrderID int,   LineOrd int,    ProductID int)
INSERT #o VALUES 
(111,   1,  10001),(2222,   1,  2001),(2222,    2,  2002),
(2222,  3,  2003),(3333,    1,  30001),(3333,   2,  30002)

DROP TABLE If exists #p
CREATE TABLE #p (OrderID int,   LinePr int, ProfileID CHAR(10))
INSERT #p VALUES 
(111,   1,  'alpha1'),(111, 2,  'bravo1'),
(2222,  1,  'charlie2'),(2222,  2,  'delta2'),
(3333,  1,  'echo3'),(3333, 2,  'hotel3')

--    select   * from #o;   select    * from #p

SELECT   
o.*, '--' f  
,p.LinePR, p.ProfileID
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.orderID, o.lineOrd ORDER BY lineOrd) rn
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.orderID, p.linePr  ORDER BY linePr ) rn2
,OrdMax = (SELECT MAX(lineOrd) FROM #o  o2 WHERE o2.OrderID = o.OrderID)
,PrMax = (SELECT MAX(linePr)   FROM #p  p2 WHERE p2.OrderID  = p.OrderID)
, 0 sw

FROM #o o
FULL JOIN #p p  ON p.orderID = o.OrderID
ORDER BY 1,2,5

-- need more cleaning
```

[image: sample Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `FULL OUTER JOIN` on both `OrderID` and `LineOrd`. And use `COALESCE()` to return first not null column of `OrderID`

```
SELECT  OrderID = COALESCE(o.OrderID, p.OrderID),
        o.LineOrd,
        o.ProductID,
        p.LinePr,
        p.ProfileID
FROM    #o o
FULL OUTER JOIN #p p    ON  p.OrderID = o.OrderID
                       AND  p.LinePr  = o.LineOrd
ORDER BY OrderID, 
         COALESCE(o.LineOrd, p.LinePr)
```

Comment: Thanks much S!!!!!!!    Just realized that in my case I didn't have OUTER. Never thought to use Lines to match!! , it works perfectly !!!

Comment: the `OUTER` keyword is optional, just my personal preference to explicitly use keyword like `INNER JOIN` rather than just simply `JOIN` etc.